# appending multiple values to single key

Tags: python

fruits.txt contains

```
avocado, green 
apple, yellow 
pear, green 
apple, green
```

im trying to print the dictionary created from the file. i try to check if the key is already in the dictionary and if not create a new key.

the printed is supposed to look like this

```
green 
     avocado 
     pear 
     apple 
yellow 
     apple
```

my code so far:

```
d = {}
file = open("fruits.txt","r")
for line in file:
    (key,val) = line.split()
    if val in d.values():
        d[val].append(key)
    else:
        d[val]=key

print(d)
```

but this only prints out

```
{'yellow': 'apple,', 'green': 'apple,'}
```

any idea as to where im going wrong in this problem?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `defaultdict` here
2. Always use `with` statement, when you are dealing with files

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict
   d = defaultdict(list)
   with open("fruits.txt","r") as inFile:
       for line in inFile:
           k, v = line.rstrip().split()
           d[v].append(k)
   ```

If you dont want to use `defaultdict`, you can use `dict` itself, like this

```
d = {}
with open("fruits.txt","r") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        k, v = line.rstrip().split()
        d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Comment: my professor hasnt taught mwe collections or with for file :(

this is exam review. thanks!

Comment: I think this code don't work because the `get` cannot initialize keys in the dict. It returns the empty list `[]`, but doesn't create the `d[v] = []` and then appends `k` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed key for values, the split character, and you have to use list as values.

```
d = {}

file_src = open("fruits.txt","r")
for line in file_src:
    (val, key) = line.strip().split(", ")
    if d.get(key):
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        d[key] = [val]

print(d)
```

Is up to you to format the final dict `d`, as this is homework.

Comment: ok i follow you. thanks! and this is a final exam review practice problem haha